# In a CRUD app, how to efficiently cache statistics data to avoid querying database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, design-patterns, database

I have a basic CRUD app with some hierarchical data, for example:

`user` --has many--> `topic` --has many--> `post`

I want to cache some statistics data, like number of posts in a topic, so it can be shown quickly to users. But I'd like to avoid querying the database and count all posts with the same topic id (I'm using *mongodb*, so no joins, but even if I use a relational database the problem is the same).

*What is the typical pattern to resolve this problem in a web app?*

Here's what I think:

### Solution 1

Store number of child elements as a property of parent element. i.e. `User.numOfTopics` will store the number of topics, when a CRUD event happened, update parent element

```
if (new topic created) {
  user = find user object from DB
  ++usr.numOfTopics;
}
```

**Pros**:

1). Simple to implement and understand

2). Accurate

**Cons**:

1). Every add/delete operation will not only update the affected element itself, but also its parent element, so I have twice as many database operations. If user add/delete a lot it may have a worse performance than counting numbers once.

2). Statistics gathering is coupled with normal business logic.

### Solution 2

Build a in-process cache of statistics dynamically. Have a separate process calculating a user's statistics when a user connect, store the result in a cache and serve future request from there. Any future CRUD operations will update the in-process cache.

**Pros**:

1). Statistics gathering is separated from business logic (sort of)

2). Less DB query, which should mean better performance.

**Cons**:

1). Cached result is not persisted, so if the server reboots it has to rebuild the cache, which will give a long latency on first visit.

2). The statistics process runs in parallel with main process so the result is subject to race conditions.

Is there a better way to deal with this problem, I have searched SO for similar questions but most refer to specific frameworks like RoR and ASP.net. I'd like to know a general design pattern if there is one, or a solution works best for node.js.

Comment: "I'd like to cache..." No, you probably don't. Step 1 is to make your database as fast as possible by tuning it. Step 2 is to make your queries as fast as possible by restructuring your database to be easy to query. Step 3 only comes into play when options 1 and 2 are exhausted because **cache invalidation is hard**.

Comment: @tadman I see your point, but my solution 1 is basically structuring the DB to make the query easier, what other common solutions are available in this use case?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: You really need to evaluate if caching is even a factor here. I see way too many stories where people spend tons of time on a caching system when the site traffic is light and they don't have a load-time issue. When you have load problems, measure them carefully, do your analysis, and fix the thing that's actually the problem, not hypothetically. You can do load-testing in advance to expose problems, but you need actual, real-world data or you'll be getting garbage results from fake data.

Comment: Your option 1 is called "counter cache" and it's a very common pattern.